# converting PHP output to JSON data but it's giving weird output

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I am using ajax method but I am fresher for PHP unable to understand my mistake

I have checked this query works fine in sql `"SELECT * FROM activity where visitorid=2";`

here my Javascript code

```
$(".followupdata").click(function(event){
    var userID=$(this).attr('uid');
   $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'getvisitordata.php',
       data:{userid:userID},
       success:function(data,status){
           console.log(data);
       }
   });        
});
```

and my getvisitordata.php code

```
include "connection.php";

$query="SELECT * FROM activity where visitorid=2";
$data=mysqli_query($query);
$jsonData=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    $jsonData[]=$row;
}
echo  json_encode($jsonData);
```

and here is output which I am getting as ajax data

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\wamp\www\access\getvisitordata.php on line *5*
>   Call
>   Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000134720{main}(  )..\getvisitordata.php**:**0 20.0600142176http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-query'
>   target='_new'>mysqli_query (  )..\getvisitordata.php**:**5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my Mistake I forgot to mention connection in query It should be mysqli_query($con,$query) instead of mysqli_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
 $data=mysqli_query($query);
 json_encode($data); //encode to json
```

Answer (score -1):

this is how to write mysqli_query

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli connection variable,$query)
```

where, with `mysqli connection variable` i mean `$mysqli`

if,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "database");
```

You are using mysql_fetch_array() which is going to be slow down things for sure.
And if i am right  more memory consumption too.

USE :

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
```